# Prove $f : A\rightarrow B, g: B\rightarrow C$ , and $g\circ f: A \overset{1-1}{\rightarrow}C$, then $f:A\overset{1-1}{\rightarrow}B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-writing

Could anyone please explain how to approach this problem, I'm honestly having a hard time figuring out where to start the problem. I know that I have to show that $\forall x,y\in A$ , if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$.

Therefore, my educated guess would be to start by letting $x,y\in A$ s.t. $f(x)=f(y)$

Comment: i think you could also try it by a contradiction argument

Comment: A nice follow-up to this exercise may be: "If $g\circ f$ is injective, and $f$ is surjective, then $g$ is injective."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $x, y \in A$ subject to $f(x) = f(y)$. Take $g$ on both sides to get

$$g(f(x)) = g(f(y))$$

Writing this as composition gives

$$(g\circ f)(x) = (g \circ f)(y)$$

What can you now conclude, knowing that $g\circ f$ is 1-1?

Comment: I just got to that part and I believe that you need to go a little further until you the $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$, which matches the definition portion of $f(x)=f(y)$ then you can say that x=y, Is my logic correct?

Comment: +1 T. Bongers; I like your answer! @KururugiSuzaku The point, I believe, is that $f(x)=f(y)\implies g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ (but not necessarily the other direction!). Of course, once you have this, you can use the injectivity of $g\circ f:A\to C$ (remember, this is the information you're given so you should use it at some point!). For example, see Brian's excellent answer above or my answer for similar but different ways of explaining this point.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Indeed. An experiment for now, perhaps a permanent one.

Comment: I know how to find your email, because I know your name and I have excellent Search Fu. :-) But thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Look at what you’re trying to prove: that $f:A\to B$ is one-to-one. Now use the definition of *one-to-one* to reduce this to a more elementary statement to prove: you want to show that if $x,y\in A$, and $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$. That’s what it means for $f$ to be one-to-one. The most straightforward approach, therefore, starts like this:

> Let $x,y\in A$ be arbitrary, and suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$; we want to show that $x=y$.

Now what do we know? We know that $g\circ f$ is one-to-one. Is there any way to apply this? First we have to get something involving $g\circ f$. That’s easy: apply $g$ to both sides of $f(x)=f(y)$.

> Clearly $g\big(f(x)\big)=g\big(f(y)\big)$, i.e., $(g\circ f)(x)=(g\circ f)(y)$.

Now use the fact that $g\circ f$ is one-to-one to conclude ... what?

Comment: +1 Brian, I'm sure you've been told this already but your contributions to this website really do make an enormous positive difference. I really appreciate them and I'm sure everyone you've helped does too. It's very nice that someone with your knowledge takes the time to answer questions at all levels of mathematics rather than just answer questions at a high level. Thank you very much for your contributions!

Comment: Hey Brian, as I explained in an answer above yours, you get  $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$, which matches the definition portion of $f(x)=f(y)$ then you can say that x=y. I also wanted to thank you for always being there to answer my questions and wonderfully explained the steps to solve them, once again thanks a lot.

Comment: @Amitesh: You’re very welcome, and thank *you*.

Comment: @Kururugi: I’d put it a little differently, but yes, that’s the basic idea. I’d say that we have $(g\circ f)(x)=(g\circ f)(y)$, and $g\circ f$ is one-to-one, so by definition $x=y$.

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove for $x,y\in A$:

(1) $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$,

as you correctly observe. However,

(2) $f(x)=f(y)\implies g(f(x))=g(f(y))$ (this is always true for maps $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$).

Can you now use the injectivity of $g\circ f:A\to C$ to conclude (1) from (2)?

In general, when you're given information such as that above about an "external map" $g:B\to C$, then you should use that information. In this case, we needed to establish (1) and we did this by observing (2) which subsequently allowed use to use something we already know (the injectivity of $g\circ f:A\to C$) to reach our conclusion (1).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the problem. As I explained in the answer below yours, $$(g\circ f)(x) = (g \circ f)(y)$$, then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$, which matches the definition portion of $f(x)=f(y)$ then you can say that $x=y$. One of the mistakes I made when I started doing the problem without writing down what I needed to show was that y was in B, which makes no sense when doing this problem.

Comment: @KururugiSuzaku You're correct that $x,y\in A$ but $f(x)=f(y)$ is not *equivalent* to $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$; rather, $f(x)=f(y)$ *implies* $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$. Otherwise, I think you've got the idea; do you think your question is answered now?